# Issue running a defined function in the PyCharm Console

Tags: python, function, console, pycharm

I'm new to python and I am stuck on this simple problem.

I want to run a function that I have defined in the console in pycharm. I have a .py file called myFunction.py and is this I have the following code.

```
def simple_addition(num1,num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    print(sum)
```

I then want to call this function from the console. I have tried typing the following

```
python myFunction.py
```

and it returns a syntax error. I have also tried typing in the console

```
from myFunction import simple_addition
```

from this i get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'simple_addition'
```

Anybody know where I am going wrong?

Comment: What does the syntax error say when you run `python myFunction.py`?

Comment: File "<input>", line 1
python MyFunction.py
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you typing `python MyFunction.py` inside the python console? You need to type that command in a terminal (Windows shell, or whatever terminal PyCharm uses on Windows, but not the Python console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo somewhere. When you open a python console in pycharm it automatically sets the cwd to the project directory. You can make sure that the .py file you want to work with is available with `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir()`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Doesn't seem to solve my issue though. Here's what I get.

Comment: please post a screen shot of your ide in the question. That way we can see if there is a misspelling or other issue in the file names.

Comment: Delete the blank lines on 2 and 4, they are causing syntax errors. you cannot import broken files.

Comment: @kpie Apparently this is solved, but just as a note, those blank lines are not syntax errors. The script runs fine with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def simple_addition(num1,num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    print(sum)

a, b = map(int, raw_input().split())

simple_addition(a, b)
```

Save it as `myFunction.py`, then run it.

Maybe that's what you want!  :)